# I was able to display the data in CloudFirestore, but I want to transfer the data to the other side of the screen

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have managed to acquire and display data using CloudFireStore, but I would like to send the acquired data to the destination screen when the screen is transferred.

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextPage('test')),
));
```

but I don't know which function to put in.

↓This code is the one that sends the data.

```
class Rigakubu extends StatefulWidget {
  const Rigakubu({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<Rigakubu> createState() => _RigakubuState();
}

class _RigakubuState extends State<Rigakubu> {
  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  List<DocumentSnapshot> documentList = [];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('理学部'),),
      body: SafeArea(
          child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: _firestore.collection('理学部').snapshots(),
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(
                    child:Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.do_disturb_on_outlined,size: 150,),
                        Text(
                          '校外のメールアドレスでログインしているため\nこの機能は利用できません。',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ],
                    )

                );
              }
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator()
                );
              }
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index){
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('zyugyoumei')),
                      subtitle: Text(snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('kousimei')),
                      onTap: (){
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => View(post: snapshot.data!.docs)),
                        );
                      }
                    );
                  }

              );
            },
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

↓This code is the code on the receiving end of the data.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

class View extends StatefulWidget {
  final int post;
  View(this.post);
  const View({Key? key, required this.post}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<View> createState() => _ViewState();
}

class _ViewState extends State<View> {
  late int state;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // 受け取ったデータを状態を管理する変数に格納
    state = widget.post;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(widget.post.bumon),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean you would like to pass the data from one screen to another?

Comment: Yes!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Post edited.
Added code for the side that receives the data.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably try this inside the **onTap** function before calling the **Navigator**

> documentList = snapshot.data!.docs;

But generally avoid passing data through constructor and try to work with state management.

Comment: Added. How do I code the side that passes the data?

Comment: that is totally upto how your requirement is, you can have the same data type in your second screen and use widgets list Listview.builder to show. Please accept the answer if it answered your questions. Thanks.

Comment: Roger that. Thanks for answering.

I'm new to Flutter so I'll do some more research.

Comment: Code reorganized. I added status management to the destination screen, but I still get an error.

Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: Not a problem, @gadgelogger but kindly take up a free flutter course to help you understand the basics of framework or you can look up on youtube too. Since the error you are getting might be specific to your code it would be difficult to answer without looking at the code or debugging.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in contacting you.

I've been researching other posts and such since then and have successfully resolved the issue.
Thank you!